# Let $k > 1$ be a positive number. There exist a $0<c<2$ such that $k = 2^{2^{2^{\cdots 2^c}}}$

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve this question from our course booklet:

Let $k > 1$ be a positive number.

Prove:

There exist a $0<c<2$ such that $k = 2^{2^{2^{\cdots 2^c}}}$

I don't have a intuition why this statement is true.

any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: What is that notation? The $2^{2^{2^{\cdots 2^c}}}$, what does this mean?

Comment: @QC_QAOA for example, if $k = 16$, we get $k = 2^{2^{2}}$

Comment: Hint: can you do it in the special case where $1 < k \leq 2$? What about the special case where $2 < k \leq 4$? How about $4 < k \leq 8$? Can you generalize this?

Comment: Okay, so the notation means you can have a power tower of as many $2$s as you want? Its not a fixed number of them?

Comment: As for intuition, just look at specific examples. Note that $2^1=2,2^2=4,2^{(2^2)}=16....$ To hit integers in between terms in this sequence, you should be able to see that we only need pick $c\in (0,2)$ (when $c=2$ we can increase the size of the power tower of 2s, which is moving to the next term in the sequence). For instance, $5=2^{(2^c)}$ for  $c\approx 1.21532$

Comment: hint: $f(x) = 2^x$ is a surjective function.

Comment: The value of the power tower grows incredibly quickly with the number of $2$'s. Even if we have $c=0$ and seven twos , this boils down to a power tower with six twos which is larger than $10^{10^{19\ 727}}$